# Insert a string variable inside a Where Clause

Tags: java, android, mysql, where-clause

How do i make the string variable `searchQuery`passed from the `SearchResultsActivity` to the `SearchResultPresenter` part of the `where clause`string. Thanks

My Activity

```
public class SearchResultsActivity ...{
...

 mPresenter.getUsers(searchQuery);

...

}
```

My Presenter

```
public class SearchResultPresenter ...{

...
public void getUsers(String searchQuery) {

String query = "....Contains(name, 'searchQuery') "; // this doesn't work, shows the method parameter `searchQuery` is never used.

String whereClause = String.format(query, ...);

}
```

}

Comment: Better to use `PreparedStatement` and *bind parameters*.  To use `String.format` is similar (with `%s` instead of `?`). `String query = "....Contains(name, '%s') ";` And then `String.format(query, searchQuery);`

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will use a PreparedStatement for this, and the parameter in the string will simply be a question mark. Something like this:

```
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "UN", "PW");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareCall("select * from table where contains(textcol,?)");
    ps.setString(1,"the string that will replace the question mark");
///in your case
ps.setString(1,searchQuery);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

If the parameter is a int, you'd do ps.setInt(...) instead.
It is also possible, but not advised, to just concatenate the value into the string, but that can open you up to all kinds of problems, so don't bother getting in the habit of doing it.

so in you code specifically, you're search string variable could just be put straight into the ps.setString() method, and your query string could be a static final class level string with a question mark in it.

Comment: Thanks @markg, Let me give it a try and revert. My immediate dilema is how i would define the active connection "con" as i am using backend as a service, precisely backendless.

Comment: well, typically the code I posted would run inside your endpoint (like in Tomcat or jetty etc on your web server) , and your service call would just take the search string param...assuming I truly understand what you're talking about ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format() to accomplish this.

```
String query = String.format("....Contains(name, '%s')", searchQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse for the edit, is this sql injection safe?

Comment: This is not a good idea unless you are sure that the string will not contain characters that will cause the full text search to throw an exception. If the searchQuery has a ' in it, it will break etc. And depending on where this statement is executed, yes, it in theory could create sql injection problems